# Windows 10- Ubuntu Dual boot factory reset

Tags: system-installation

I’m trying to factory reset my Windows 10 Ubuntu dual boot laptop. What are the best steps for this? Do I need to delete Ubuntu before factory resetting on the windows side?

Comment: Do you want to keep your Ubuntu partition? If not, you still dont need to remove it before hand, you can reformat the disk at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have your installation disk for Windows, then use that to install Windows 10 from scratch. If no, then use the [Windows installation media creator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-create-installation-media) to create a boot able USB drive, then use that to reinstall Windows. When you get to the part where it asks you if you want to "upgrade" or "do something else", Select Do something else. Use the tool to delete all the partitions and create a new one to install Windows on.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through this with my laptop.  I'm reinstalling for my own use, so I wasn't too worried about erasing the disk (as I might have been if I was preparing the laptop for sale).

I just booted using Ubuntu from CD, removed the Ubuntu partitions on the hard disk, then re-booted from the Windows CD, deleted, formatted, re-installed ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want erase Ubuntu with all file i suggest [GParted live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Download the file you like, CD/DVD/USB/PXE/HD, and burn it on the peripheral. Reboot PC and on boot press the HOTKEY to enter in boot menu, then select the peripheral with GParted. GParted live does not require installation to work. When the OS is ready run GParted and erase the partition with Ubuntu.

[img GParted live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evjML.png)

This is GParted live.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are included as follows.

**If you want to remove Ubuntu only**

1. Check whether your EFI partition of Ubuntu is separate or installed within Windows EFI using the disk management utility.
2. If it's combined, check out the video reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwcfzCfkQgc&list=PLHFHmtgV9NpL5BIrqZcZL6efq6c2SGx3C
3. If not combined, go to the diskpart in Windows, then simply delete the EFI, Root and Swap of Ubuntu.

**If you want to reset the PC, including Windows and Ubuntu, completely**

1. Directly create a bootable USB for Windows and install it.
2. While installing, do not forget to delete all the partitions.
3. After installing Windows, you may proceed to install Ubuntu.